# End user selection of currency on an InfoPath form

Tags: 2013, infopath, form

I have an InfoPath form in Sharepoint for filling in Purchase Orders.

However, being an international business; we work in British Pounds, Euros, and Swedish Kronor. As far as I can see at present, currency fields in Sharepoint must have a pre-selected currency to use.

Is there a way I can prompt the use for this on the InfoPath form; so that they can choose from 3 currencies in a drop down menu, and the form will be saved as a list item with the appropriate currency displayed when it is opened.

Many thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a currency column for each currency type, then create a calculated column to display the currency as a string.

```
 IF([CurrencyUSD]>0,"$"&[CurrencyUSD],IF([CurrencyGBP]>0,"£"&[CurrencyGBP],IF([CurrencyKR]>0,"kr. "&[CurrencyKR],""))
```

Use this calculated column for SharePoint list views. On the InfoPath side, create a dropdown for each currency and (if they aren't already there from when you created the columns) one text box per currency type. Ensure these boxes are going to the correct fields on SharePoint. Add a formatting rule to each textbox to hide it if its currency type isn't selected. For added reliability and smooth user experience, add an action rule (or rules) on the dropdown to clear the text boxes of non-selected currencies after transferring their contents into whichever one was selected.